# Linq lambda null-coalescing a nullable int

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a Category Model which has a **ParentID** field of **int?** datatype.
I'm trying to achieve this:

```
WHERE 
    ISNULL(ParentID,0) == ParentCategoryID
```

... in linq but seem to be struggling because it's telling me I can't apply **??** to ParentID as it's a nullable integer.

```
IList<Category> ChildCategories = AllCategoriesAsList
    .Where(c => c.ParentID ?? 0 == ParentCategoryID)
    .ToList();
```

I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this could do

```
IList<Category> ChildCategories = AllCategoriesAsList
    .Where(c => (c.ParentID.HasValue ? c.ParentID.Value : 0) == ParentCategoryID)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I didn't even know about 'HasValue'. Fantastic. Thanks alex

Answer (score 1):

Not really answering your question directly, but note that using [ISNULL() in a Where filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752567/adding-additional-where-clause-in-sql-takes-big-performance-hit) can lead to table / index scans

```
WHERE      ISNULL(ParentID,0) == ParentCategoryID
```

can be rewritten as

```
WHERE (ParentId is NULL AND ParentCategoryId = 0) OR (ParentId = ParentCategoryId)
```

which generally should have better performance. The LINQ equivalent would similarly also avoid the coalescing issue.

Comment: I'll take that on-board for future queries. Thanks nonnb